# Regex matching with pattern and matches

Tags: java, pattern-matching, matcher

I am reading input from file it contains set of lines as below :

```
 
    BDI100                 172.20.1.5      YES TFTP   up                    up
    BDI500                 172.20.1.50     YES TFTP   up                    up
    BDI600                 172.20.1.58     YES TFTP   up                    up
```

I have to extract the complete line which contains only 172.20.1.5

Below is my code :

```
while ((line = lineNumberReader.readLine()) != null) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(expr.trim()); /*expr is filter contains 172.20.1.5 */
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        if(m.find()){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

I am expexting output as :

```
BDI100                 172.20.1.5      YES TFTP   up                    up
```

But is printing all the lines.

Comment: try this `Pattern.compile("172\\.20\\.1\\.5\\s");`

Comment: Note that you can move the creation of `p` (better give variables meaningful names! Not `p` and `m`) outside the loop. Compiling a pattern is an expensive operation.

Comment: Do you specifically need a regexp for this scenario? Just a simple contains() may help ?

Comment: expr used for filtering can be anything it can be 172.20.1.5 or BDI100

Answer (score 2):

This will help you:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] lines = new String[]{"BDI100                 172.20.1.5      YES TFTP   up                    up",
            "BDI500                 172.20.1.50     YES TFTP   up                    up",
            "BDI600                 172.20.1.58     YES TFTP   up                    up"};
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("172\\.20\\.1\\.5\\s");
        for (String line : lines) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing seems a little excessive. Perhaps try this:

```
String need = "172.20.1.5";
String line = "";
while ((line = lineNumberReader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.trim().equals("")) {
        continue:
    }
    if (line.contains(need) {
        System.out.println(line);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Intialize expr within braces */
String expr = "(172.20.1.5 )";
while ((line = lineNumberReader.readLine()) != null) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(expr.trim()); /*expr is filter contains 172.20.1.5 */
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        if(m.find()){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```